# unable to add subfolders in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My project is running in a bluehost server where I intend to write a htaccess file. My website is a just a landing page so written in raw php. 
Folder structure is 
/current Directory >

```
- css 
- fonts
- image
   - page1
   - page2
   - page3
- js
- template
- index.php
```

I have written a htaccess file for public_html/ folder and another file for current_directory.

current htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|fonts|image|js|template)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My webpage is loaded but I am unable to add any images. I have tried with adding a htaccess file in image directory but it did not work. 
My question is

Where should I add all the project directory? Is there anyway to automate this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I jst tried. It did not work.

Comment: Or use an absolute path for images.

Comment: how to use absolute path for image? 
I used this 
<img src="image/page1/page1.jpg" />

Comment: `<img src="/image/page1/page1.jpg" />`

Comment: adding absolute path did not work.

Comment: RewriteRule /(.*)\.(jpg)$ /image/$1.$2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question but if the problem you have is that you need to manage images you need to add the following code to your .httaccess

```
<Directory /var/www/public_html/current_directory/image>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The .httaccess should be in /var/www/public_html